# android, push documents from pc to android device

Tags: android, push

How  to push documents from  PC(windows) to  android device/emulator?Do  you have any  sample  source code or  idea?Kindly sent  your  reply

Regards,
Malathi.

Comment: What do u want to install apk or any file

Answer (score 0):

http://www.androidaz.com/development/how-install-application-and-copy-files-android-emulator

accept answer if its helpful

steps:  run android application

open file explorere [eclipse =windows>show view>file explorer

you will see a window .insert there

details tutorial

http://www.apurbadebnath.com/blog/android/android-emulator-tips/

click right if you accept the answer